# How to call a method while another method is still running- Python

Tags: python

I'm working on a python program that extracts the sound from a given YouTube video url and plays it. I created a `play_vid` method to play the sound and a `pause_vid` method to pause the sound. The issue is that while the sound is still playing inside the `play_vid` method and I try to call the `pause_vid` method, the call gets ignored and the `play_vid` method keeps running. Example:

```
vid = Video("youtubelink")
vid.play_vid()
time.sleep(5)
# The sound keeps playing/this method call is being ignored
vid.pause_vid()
```

How do I terminate the `play_vid` method when the `pause_vid` method is called? I've been researching for a while and wasn't able to find a solution to this problem. Full program:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time, os, vlc, requests
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3


class InvalidUrl(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message="Invalid video url!"):
        super().__init__(message)


class Video:
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        self.paused = False
        self.player = ""
        self.is_valid()
        self.time_sleep = 0

    def play_vid(self):
        driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\chromedriver.exe")
        driver.get("https://ytmp3.cc/en14/")
        element = driver.find_element_by_id("input")
        element.send_keys(self.url)
        button = driver.find_element_by_id("submit")
        button.click()
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        button2 = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="buttons"]/a[1]')))
        button2.click()
        vid_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="title"]').text
        vid_name = vid_name.replace("| ", "")
        file_name = os.path.expanduser(r"~\Downloads\{}.mp3".format(vid_name))

        while not os.path.exists(file_name):
            time.sleep(1)

        driver.close()
        self.player = vlc.MediaPlayer()
        media = vlc.Media(file_name)
        self.player.set_media(media)
        self.player.play()
        audio = MP3(file_name)
        audio_info = audio.info
        length_in_secs = int(audio_info.length)

        while self.time_sleep != length_in_secs:
            if self.paused is True:
                return

            time.sleep(1)
            self.time_sleep += 1

    def pause_vid(self):
        self.paused = True

    def is_valid(self):
        r = requests.get(self.url)

        if "Video unavailable" in r.text:
            raise InvalidUrl
```

A big thanks to Mark M for letting me know that I forgot to add `self.player.set_pause(1)` in the `pause_vid` method. He also advised me to remove the while loop, so I used `time.sleep` in my main program in order to decide how long the video will play for instead of the while loop. Updated code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time, os, vlc, requests
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3


class InvalidYouTubeUrl(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message="Invalid YouTube url!"):
        super().__init__(message)


class Video:
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        self.player = None
        self.is_valid()
        self.vid_len = None

    def play_vid(self):
        driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\chromedriver.exe")
        driver.get("https://ytmp3.cc/en14/")
        element = driver.find_element_by_id("input")
        element.send_keys(self.url)
        button = driver.find_element_by_id("submit")
        button.click()
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        button2 = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="buttons"]/a[1]')))
        button2.click()
        vid_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="title"]').text
        vid_name = vid_name.replace("| ", "")
        file_name = os.path.expanduser(r"~\Downloads\{}.mp3".format(vid_name))

        while not os.path.exists(file_name):
            time.sleep(1)

        driver.close()
        self.player = vlc.MediaPlayer()
        media = vlc.Media(file_name)
        self.player.set_media(media)
        self.player.play()
        audio = MP3(file_name)
        audio_info = audio.info
        self.vid_len = int(audio_info.length)

    def pause_vid(self):
        self.player.set_pause(1)

    def is_valid(self):
        r = requests.get(self.url)

        if "Video unavailable" in r.text:
            raise InvalidYouTubeUrl
```

I've also found a way to play the whole sound in the main program:

```
import pyytmp3, time

vid = pyytmp3.Video("youtubelink")
vid.play_vid()
time.sleep(vid.vid_len)
```

I'm basically just delaying the program by the length of the video.

Comment: You can run the `play_vid` method on a dedicated thread or task while calling `pause_vid` in the main thread. Check the [threading](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/threading.html) and/or [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/asyncio.html) modules

Comment: @dc_Bita98, can you please show me how to implement `threading` and `asyncio` in my program? I'm just not very familiar with these modules and an example of how to use them in my program would help a lot

Comment: @Roni I am pretty sure that there are dozens of examples all over the internet.

Comment: To put it in more familiar terms, `play_vid` is *blocking*, it waits until the video is done playing to return (to your code). However, you need `play_vid` to be *nonblocking*, meaning it returns immediately once the audio is up and running. Looking at your `play_vid`, what stands out is the while loop that `sleep`s until `time_sleep` reaches the length of the video. That's the part that's making `play_vid` blocking. Try removing that while loop and `time_sleep`.

Comment: @BatWannaBe, but without the while loop the sound will not play. In the `vlc` module, you need to use `time.sleep` in order to wait until the sound finishes playing. Otherwise, it won't play in the first place

Comment: well, you have the `time.sleep(5)` in your main script for that.

Comment: @BatWannaBe, the `time_sleep(5)` is for testing the program. I just wanted to see if the sound will actually stop after 5 seconds

Comment: It's worth a shot. The original `vlc`'s `play` requires that you write your own `sleep(duration)` to keep the video/audio playing, so why can't your custom `play_vid` work the same way? You call `play_vid()`, it returns, and it's up to you to `sleep` for 5 seconds or however long you want until you pause.

Comment: @BatWannaBe, not a bad idea. I'll try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is two-fold:

1. You're not actually pausing the audio playback, so the `MediaPlayer` will just continue to play the rest of it. According to the [MediaPlayer](https://www.olivieraubert.net/vlc/python-ctypes/doc/vlc.MediaPlayer-class.html) docs it has a function `pause()` or even `stop()`. Call this from your pause_vid method.
2. <s>You'll need to invoke the `vid.pause_vid()` method from another thread because the play_vid() method will just run till completion. You can create a background thread to play the video from. Some good examples here https://pymotw.com/3/threading/</s> On second thought, I think the `MediaPlayer.play()` method already runs in the background due to the wording in the documentation:

> Play.
> @return: 0 if playback started (and was already started), or -1 on error.

Comment: I added the pause function, now I'm working on learning how to add a thread

Comment: On second thought I think the MediaPlayer object already runs in the background, that would mean you don't need any threading yourself. Can you try with just the .pause() addition?

Comment: I've tried that already, but the `pause_vid` method isn't being called anyway since `play_vid` is still running

Comment: That may be because of your while loop at the end. What if you comment all the lines below `self.player.play()`?